# Is there a general matrix form for Ohm's law in relation to a graph representation of a circuit? (To solve for current, for instance)

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, linear-algebra

Given a graph representation (weighted adjacency matrix) of a circuit with current sources and resistances (current values at nodes and resistances as graph edges), is there a general matrix format for Ohm's law to solve for the node current values? I've been building my own matrix form for this, but I'd much rather not re-invent the wheel if this form is already known.

Comment: Are you familiar with graph Laplacians and Kirchhoff polynomials? If not, those are good things to Google. Kirchhoff did not only write down his loop equations, but he also gave a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The most common approach is [nodal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_analysis), where you write Ohm's law as $GV=I$ where G is conductance. This generalizes when $G$ is a matrix of conductances with $V$ and $I$ as vectors of voltage and current.

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I was looking for.